# Get categories within specific term

Tags: wp-query, categories, woocommerce-offtopic, loop, terms

I have a WooCommerce shop, where I'd like to show every possible product category, where the products have a specific attribute (term). Say I have a product attribute called: "Designer", then I wish to find all the categories where products have attribute Designer => "Nike".

So essentially the output would be:

**Nike categories:**

- Shoes
- Hats
- Pants

Any pointers in the right direction where I can solve this?

Comment: Just have a look at wphierachy.com - it tells you the template logic, same with woocommerce. See https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/ In your case I believe (I'm not 100% sure) your template name in your theme would be taxonomy-product-designer-nike.php or is_product_tag( array( 'Designer' )) The query in that template has to be prepared/specified via pre_get_posts. I know it's not a full answer, but maybe you are getting into the right direction.

Comment: *is_product_tag() in your template file